# Magento2 model save() method connected to db table structure in the install schema

Tags: magento2, model, install-script

I have a basic model - **MyModel**.
The install schema for the table that the model is working with is

```
$setup
->getConnection()
->newTable('my_table')
->addColumn(
    'id',
    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
    null,
    ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' =>
        false, 'primary' => true],
    'primary key'
)
->addColumn(
    'start_date',
    Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
    null,
    ['nullable' => true],
    'start date'
)
->addColumn(
    'end_date',
    Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
    null,
    ['nullable' => true],
    'end date'
);
```

The format of the data that can be saved in a db field of type **DATETIME** must be the fallowing

```
'Y-m-d' => '2017-12-13'
```

When I execute the fallowing code

```
$myModel->setData([
 'start_date'=>'13-12-2017',
 'end_date'=>'15-12-2017'   
]);
$myModel->save();
```

I explicitly set the date string to be in the wrong format - **'d-m-Y'**. The weirdest thing happens. I get no SQL error and the dates are saved in the DB in the right format and the **start_date** and **end_date** values are saved correctly and the result looks like that:

```
id  start_date          end_date
1   2017-12-13 00:00:00 2017-12-15 00:00:00
```

How does the model's **save()** method know which values should be of type  **DATETIME** and how does it convert that value to the desired format for storing in the DB.

Comment: Change your table column datetime to date.

Comment: this is not what I am asking and the question is not how to save in the format d-m-Y but what transforms the wrong format to the right one and how does Magento know which columns are DATETIME so it can try to transform the values to the correct format for them